# Оптимизация JS + баг

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день! Сделал JS под Slick Slider, который реализует вместе со сменой слайда появление активного элемента в списке слайдов + смена слайдов от наведения на пункт списка пользователем.

Беда в том что это мой первый скрипт и мне кажется, что его можно сделать раза в 2 короче (через переменные, дочерние элементы *(крутые штуки о которых я пока мало в JS знаю :)* )

Также заметил что существует баг, при **быстром** перемещении мышки **с 1го на 3й (проходя 2й)** скрип зависает на среднем, втором пункте. Для того чтобы сработал целевой слайд нужно сначала увести курсор на боковое поле а потом повторно на необходимый пунк. Есть идея сделать задержку на выполнение функции `.hover`, но я не знаю на сколько это правильно и поможет ли.

Уважаемые, форумчане, жду Вашего толкового совета:) Спасибо!

Код и скрин ниже

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Синяя стрела - перемещение курсора (по прямой только, не гнуто как я нарисовал)

Красная - это движение, которое необходимо сделать чтоб поменялся слайд и подсветился 3й пункт.

Если перемещать медленно мышь - то все норм.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.second_slick').slick({
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 3000,
    arrows: false,
    dots: false,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    fade: true,
    centerPadding: 0,
    initialSlide: 0 })


$('.second_ul_li_h2').hover(function(active_slide) {
    $('.second_slick').slick('slickPause');

    if (active_slide.currentTarget.id == 'second_ul_li_h20'){
        $('.second_slick').slick('slickGoTo', 0);
    }
    if (active_slide.currentTarget.id == 'second_ul_li_h21'){
        $('.second_slick').slick('slickGoTo', 1);
    }
    if (active_slide.currentTarget.id == 'second_ul_li_h22'){
        $('.second_slick').slick('slickGoTo', 2);
    }
}, function() { 
    $('.second_slick').slick('slickPlay');
});

$('.second_slick').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
        if (currentSlide == '0') {
            $('.second_ul_li_check').css("transform", "scale(0)"); 
            $('#check0').css("transform", "scale(1)");  };
        if (currentSlide == '1') {
            $('.second_ul_li_check').css("transform", "scale(0)"); 
            $('#check1').css("transform", "scale(1)");  };
        if (currentSlide == '2') {
            $('.second_ul_li_check').css("transform", "scale(0)");
            $('#check2').css("transform", "scale(1)"); };
    });
});
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <link rel="icon" href="./favicon.ico">

        <title>F-System`s</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap grid CSS -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap-grid.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Подключение шрифта -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700&amp;subset=cyrillic" rel="stylesheet">  
        <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
        <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Подключение слик-слайдера -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick-theme.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fontello.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css"/>
    </head>
<body>
<div class="container">
            <div class="second">
                <ul class="second_ul">
                    <li class="second_ul_li" id="second_ul_li_0">
                        <div class="second_ul_li_check" id="check0"></div>
                        <p>1</p>
                        <h2 class="second_ul_li_h2" id="second_ul_li_h20">Уберем плесень и грибок<br><span>Паром при 120°С</span></h2>
                        <img id="second_clean_img" src="../img/clean-dirty.png">
                    </li>
                    <li class="second_ul_li" id="second_ul_li_1">
                        <div class="second_ul_li_check" id="check1"></div>
                        <p>2</p>
                        <h2 class="second_ul_li_h2" id="second_ul_li_h21">Закрепим эффект немецкой <br>химией <span>CONDICLEAN™</span></h2>
                        <img id="second_antiseptic_img" src="../img/antiseptic.png">
                    </li>
                    <li class="second_ul_li" id="second_ul_li_2">
                        <div class="second_ul_li_check" id="check2"></div>
                        <p>3</p>    
                        <h2 class="second_ul_li_h2" id="second_ul_li_h22">Почистим дренаж - <br><span>Устраним на 100% риск</span><br> протечки и неприятного запаха</h2>
                        <img id="second_smell_img" src="../img/smell.png">
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="second_nav">
                    <a href="#">Это только начало!</a>
                    <div class="second_nav_arrows"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="second_scont">
                    <div class="second_slick">
                        <div><img id="second_clean_img" src="../img/clean-dirty.png"></div>
                        <div><img id="second_antiseptic_img" src="../img/antiseptic.png"></div>
                        <div><img id="second_smell_img" src="../img/smell.png"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>


    </body>
```

CSS:

```
.second {
  height: 686px;
  position: relative;
}
.second_ul {
  display: flex-block;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  float: right;
  height: 686px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
.second_ul_li {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  margin: 50px 0px;
}
.second_ul_li:first-child {
  margin-top: 132px;
}
.second_ul_li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
.second_ul_li_check {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0px 1px;
  width: 77px;
  height: 77px;
  border: 2px solid RGB(250, 68, 8);
  border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
          transform: scale(0);
}
.second_ul_li p {
  font-size: 72px;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin: 0px 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.second_ul_li h2 {
  margin: 8px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 34px;
}
.second_ul_li span {
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.second_ul_li img {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  max-width: 550px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}
.second_scont {
  display: block;
  width: 550px;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
.second_scont_slick img {
  -o-object-fit: cover;
     object-fit: cover;
}
.second_nav {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}
.second_nav_arrows {
  margin: 10px 0px;
  position: relative;
  width: 8px;
  height: 17px;
  background: #2d2d2d;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.second_nav_arrows::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border: 12px solid transparent;
  border-top: 12px solid #2d2d2d;
  position: absolute;
  top: 17px;
  right: -8px;
}
.second_nav_arrows:hover {
  background: RGB(250, 68, 8);
  opacity: 1;
}
.second_nav_arrows:hover::after {
  border-top: 12px solid RGB(250, 68, 8);
}
.second_nav a {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #2d2d2d;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Код и скрин ниже© а где скрин. а ещё, если кусок кода рабочий его можно вставить кнопкой `фрагмент кода`(справа от кнопки `изображение`)

Comment: Добавил, спасибо